# Import React Material UI Icons dynamically error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite

hello im trying to dynamicly load icon from mui this is the code

```
import React from "react";
import * as MuiIcons from "@mui/icons-material";
console.log("MuiIcons: ", MuiIcons);

const Icon = ({ iconName }) => {
        return <div>{MuiIcons[iconName]}</div>;
};

export default Icon;
```

but i get this error instead

```
react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:9)
    at reconcileChildFibers2 (react-dom.development.js:15828:7)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:28)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:19924:3)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21618:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
```

any idea how to solve it ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are importing an object not a react component.

To use it this way you can do something like this:

```
const Icon = ({ iconName }) => {
  const Icon = MuiIcons[iconName]
  return <Icon />
}
```